# How to format sd/mmc partition to cramfs

Tags: linux, filesystems

First, is it possible to format a sd/mmc partition to cramfs filesystem? If the answer is yes please show me how can I perform that.

Note: I am not asking about how to create a cramfs image, I have already created such image for Ramdisk.

Comment: If you have already created an image then you just write it onto the device (e.g. with `dd`). Where exactly are you running into a problem?

Comment: @Celada: Usually, I use ext2 filesystem for my mmc. Hence, I have to create a partition, then beofre loading the filesystem content (files and directories) the partition must be already formatted to ext2 fs using mkfs.ext2. I am asking how to format the partition I have to Cramfs rather than ext2? Is it enough to copy the image using dd without formatting the partition?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the image without formatting the partition"? If you put an ext2 filesystem image on the partition (using `mkfs.ext2`, normally) the partition now has an ext2 filesystem; if you put a cramfs image on the partition it has a cramfs filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about how cramfs **images** are created.  One doesn't typically create a cramfs **filesystem** as cramfs is a read-only filesystem, so the entire image -- filesystem structure and contents -- are created in one go.

If the OP is asking how to copy a cramfs image so that it resides within an ext2 filesystem, you'd create the image in the usual fashion, using mkfs.cramfs, then copy the resultant image file into some directory in the ext2 filesystem, then mount that image with "mount -t cramfs /path/to/cramfs/image /mount/point".  The image is simply yet another file within the ext2 filesystem.

The more common use of cramfs is storing the image into a partition as the only filesystem within that partition.  In that instance, you would create the cramfs image in the same manner as before, then copy the entire image to the partition using the appropriate tools.  There is no need to format the partition first as the cramfs image will over-write whatever was previously written there.  The same "mount -t cramfs /path/to/image /mount/point" approach is used here as well, with the caveat that there is no cramfs partition type as there is with ext2 and others and */path/to/image* is typically going to reside within */dev*.